# How to set up UITextFieldDelegate for multiple text fields?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I can't run code like this, what's wrong?
It doesn’t work for all textfield, but rather only one of them.

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newlenght1 = (textField1.text?.utf16.count)! + string.utf16.count - range.length // I have 3 textfield and I want for all of them same rule
    let newlenght2 = (textField2.text?.utf16.count)! + string.utf16.count - range.length // I have 3 textfield and I want for all of them same rule
    let newlenght3 = (textField3.text?.utf16.count)! + string.utf16.count - range.length // I have 3 textfield and I want for all of them same rule
    let allowedCharacters = "ABCDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ" // I only this charachters // allowed characters
    let characthers = CharacterSet(charactersIn: allowedCharacters)
    let charactersType = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    let finalCharacters = characthers.isSuperset(of: charactersType)
    
    if textField == textField1 && textField == textField2 && textField == textField3 && newlenght1 <= 1 && newlenght2 <= 1 && newlenght3 <= 1 {
        return finalCharacters // but don't work for all textfield ,worked for only 1 textfield
    }else{
        return false
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this ever does anything but return false. Your `if` is unsatisfiable. You are saying "if this is an apple and this is an orange", but how could it ever be both?

Comment: You say that it only works for one textfield. That leads me to believe that the outlets for textField1, textField2, textField3 are all connected to the same textfield on your storyboard. It won't solve everything but it's something you should check.

Comment: @JarWarren I want to ensure that only one letter is entered in all different textfields.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I want all text fields to be able to write only one letter.thats why i used &&

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you are trying to achieve.  The logic in the example is flawed so we can't be certain what outcome you are aiming for, and therefore the best way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to have all three text fields follow the same rule, set the `delegate` for all three. The `shouldChangeCharactersIn` only needs to check the “current” text field into which the user is currently typing.

A minor observation, but I also would avoid recreating the `CharacterSet` of allowed characters repeatedly. You can simply make that a property.

That reduces it down to something like:

```swift
private let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ")

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (textField.text?.count ?? 0) - range.length + string.count > 1 {
        return false
    }

    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: string.localizedUppercase))
}
```

---

If you want them only entering uppercase characters, I would:

- Change the keyboard capitalization to “All Characters”, so they are more likely to not enter lowercase letters:

  [image]
- Optionally change the capitalization by adding an “editing changed” action for your text field to:

  ```swift
  @IBAction func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
      textField.text = textField.text?.localizedUppercase
  }
  ```

  You might have to experiment whether you want to use `localizedUppercase` or `uppercased()` or `uppercased(with:)`.

  Note, this “uppercase the whole string” logic is a little sloppy. If you were allowing multi-character strings in your input, you really would want to capture where the cursor was and restore it. (Otherwise it could be an annoying UX where if the user is changing the first character of a multi-character string, the cursor would jump to the end.) E.g., a simple rendition might be:

  ```swift
  @IBAction func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
      let range = textField.selectedTextRange
      textField.text = textField.text?.localizedUppercase
      textField.selectedTextRange = range
  }
  ```

  But for your single character input, the simpler example, above, should be sufficient.

Comment: when I use this code, can't use backspace and can't delete what I type.And its force me to open caps lock for type any string to textfield.

Comment: Well, your allowed characters only included upper case letters. You can `uppercased` it if you want to allow lowercase letters. Re delete, that was a mistake in my string length logic, which I've fixed, above.

Comment: I mean, I want force user only can type uppercased ,without need caps lock button.transform to uppercased whatever type,

 like 

 “(textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.uppercased())“

Comment: Yeah, that’s effectively what I’m doing in the “editing changed” action method (which I hooked up in IB). You really don’t want to be updating the text field in `shouldChangeCharactersIn`, IMHO. But setting the keyboard “capitalization” setting, the user will get a keyboard with “caps lock” already set. (But you want to still uppercase it in case the user deselects the caps lock manually or pastes in a lowercase string.)

Comment: you are amazing thanks again :)